# error: could not find target(s): MyLib; use the 'path' property in the Swift 4 manifest to set a custom target path

Tags: swift4, swift-package-manager

I am running `sudo swift test` and got following error:

> **error**: could not find target(s): MyLib; use the 'path' property in the Swift 4 manifest to set a custom target path

#### Package.swift:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:4.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLib",
    targets: [
        .target(name: "MyLib"),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyLibTests",
            dependencies: ["MyLib"])
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0162-package-manager-custom-target-layouts.md#impact-on-existing-code) there is an impact on exiting code. The purposal says:

> These enhancements will be added to the **version 4** manifest API, which will release with *Swift 4*. There will be **no** impact on packages using the **version 3** manifest API. When packages update their *minimum tools version* to 4.0, they will need to update the manifest according to the changes in this proposal.

Since your **minimum tools version** is `4.0`, you must add `path: "path/to/sources"` in `.Target()`.

Your `Package.swift` should look like this:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:4.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLib",
    targets: [
        .target(
           name: "MyLib",
           path: "Sources"), //path for target to look for sources
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyLibTests",
            dependencies: ["MyLib"],
            path: "Tests")
    ]
)
```